# Subtract the aggregation of two sums in a view in Django

Tags: django

Im trying to create a profit field, so im taking two aggregations of sums and subtracting them. Unfortunately, I can't seem to do it this way. Is there a way of accomplishing this? I'd use the model, but im not calling it in the template

```
def view(request):
    result_list = Result.objects.order_by('-entryID')[:5]
    from django.db.models import Sum
    winnings = Result.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('winnings'), Sum('entry'))
    >>>>>>>>> profit = winnings.winnings__sum - winnings.entry__sum <<<<<<<<<<<

    template = loader.get_template('result.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'result_list': result_list,
        'winnings': winnings,
        'profit': profit,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aggregate` returns a dictionary:

```
profit = winnings["winnings__sum"] - winnings["entry__sum"]
```

That's why `winnings.winnings__sum` works in a template but not in python.

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway to get profit as part of the winnings dictionary?